# DataTables: sort by numeric data-order not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables version 1.10. I want to make a column sortable by a numeric value, when the value shown in the column is not numeric.

I can see that [what I need to do is add a `data-sort` attribute](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) to each table cell. I've tried adding this with the `createdRow` method, but although I can see the attribute in the HTML, it's not sorting numerically.

This is my code:

```
var data = [
      {
          'name': 'France',
          'played': 1000,
          'won': 11
      },
      {
          'name': 'England',
          'played': 1000,
          'won': 100
      },
      {
          'name': 'Germany',
          'played': 1000,
          'won': 109
      }
  ];
    $.each(data, function(i, d) {
        d.won_percent = (d.won / d.played) * 100;
        d.won_display = d.won + '/' + d.played;
        d.won_display += ' (';
        d.won_display += Math.round(d.won_percent * 10) / 10;
        d.won_display += '%)';
    });
  var columns = [
    { "data": "name",
      "title": "Country"
    },
    { "data": "won_display",
      "title": "Games won"
    },
    { "data": null,
      "title": "Notes",
     "defaultContent": 'Some other text here, included just to test that responsive works'
    }  
  ];
  var html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable"></table>';
  $('#table').html(html);
  $("#myTable").DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: columns,
    order:[[1, "desc"]],
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    createdRow: function (row, data, rowIndex) {
      $.each($('td', row), function (colIndex) {
        if (colIndex === 1) {
          $(this).attr('data-order', data.won_percent);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How can I get my table to sort by the value of `d.won_percent`?

Note that I'm also building a responsive table, which means that I need to be careful about using render events.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/07nk5wob/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [orthogonal data](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) which is the term jQuery DataTables uses for a way of providing different data for display, sort and filter operations.

Also you need to explicitly state column data type with `type: "num"`.

```js
$.each(data, function (i, d) {
    d.won_percent = {
        sort: (d.won / d.played) * 100
    };
    d.won_percent.display = 
        d.won + '/' + d.played +
        ' (' + Math.round(d.won_percent.sort * 10) / 10 + '%)';
});

// ... skipped ...

{
    "data": "won_percent",
    "title": "Games won",
    "type": "num",
    "render": {
        "_": "display",
        "sort": "sort"
    }
},
```

> **DEMO**

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07nk5wob/35/) for code and demonstration.

> **LINKS**

- [Orthogonal data example](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data)

Comment: Actually I'm afraid it's not working properly. See here with updated numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/07nk5wob/34/

Comment: @Richard, I have corrected my code, Apparently DataTables doesn't do type detection when orthogonal data is used so it needs to be stated explicitly with `type: "num"`.

Answer (score 5):

here is a **native** way of doing it

add this "columnDefs" object inside the datatables settings object

```
  columnDefs: [
  { 
     targets: [1], // cell target
         render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
             if(type === "sort") {
                var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
                var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node(); // the td of the row
                data = $(td).attr('data-order'); // the data it should be sorted by
             }
             return data;
         }
     },
  ],
```

here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/07nk5wob/6/

Comment: This code it's just awesome! @Enjoyted you save me a week of researching, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/07nk5wob/9/

Basically you need a `special` sorting thingie:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
   "special-pre": function ( a ) {
       var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
       var matches = regExp.exec(a);
       return parseFloat(matches[1]);
   },
   "special-asc": function ( a, b ) {
       return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
   },
   "special-desc": function ( a, b ) {
       return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/07nk5wob/25/) for your problem.

You can implement your own sorting plugin to do that. It is quite simple. Here I have extend the DataTable plugin by adding a `percentage` sorting method. You can see in the `percentage-pre` method, I'm only returning the numeric value which you want to sort.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
   "percentage-pre": function ( a ) {
       var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
       var matches = regExp.exec(a);
       var exactVal = matches[1];
       return parseFloat(exactVal.slice(0, -1));
   },
   "percentage-asc": function ( a, b ) {
       return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
   },
   "percentage-desc": function ( a, b ) {
       return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
   }
});
```

Then in the above fiddle you can see, I am adding below code in DataTable init method:

```
columnDefs: [
   { type: 'percentage', targets: 1 }
 ]
```

Hope this is what you need!