# How to use orthogonal data to sort in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) v1.10. I want to make a column sortable by a numeric value, when the value shown in the column is not numeric.

I understand that I need to use [orthogonal data](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) to do this, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33609100/194000).

However, my sort function is not working. This is my code:

```
var myData = [{
    'country': 'France',
        'all_games': 7,
        'won_games': 4
}, {
    'country': 'England',
        'all_games': 13,
        'won_games': 13
}, {
    'country': 'Germany',
        'all_games': 2,
        'won_games': 0
}];
var columns = [{
    "data": "country",
        "title": "Country"
}, {
    "data": "outcomes_str",
        "title": 'Games won',
        "render": {
        "_": "display",
            "sort": "sort"
    }
}];
$.each(myData, function (i, d) {
    d.outcomes_str = {};
    d.outcomes_str.sort = (d.all_games > 0) ? (d.won_games / d.all_games) * 100 : 0;
    d.outcomes_str.display = d.won_games + '/' + d.all_games + ' (' + Math.round(d.outcomes_str.sort * 10) / 10 + '%)';
    console.log(d.outcomes_str);
});
drawTable(myData, 'localTable');

function drawTable(data, tableId) {
    var html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover ';
    html += '" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable"></table>';
    $('#table').append(html);
    $("#myTable").DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: columns,
        paging: false
    });
}
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/07nk5wob/33/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [my corrected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33609100/3549014).

Basically, you need to explicitly state column data type with `type: "num"` for numeric data, otherwise it may default to alphabetical sort.

```js
{
    "data": "outcomes_str",
    "title": 'Games won',
    "type": "num",
    "render": {
        "_": "display",
        "sort": "sort"
    }
}
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07nk5wob/35/) for code and demonstration.